# Idiomatic way of returning a not-found error in Golang?

Tags: go

I have a function with this signature in Go:

```golang
func GetAccount(ctx context.Context, id uuid.UUID) (*Account, error)
```

It returns an error if there's an internal error (like the database query fails for some reason), but I'm not sure what I should return if the account is not found. I can think of two different approaches:

1. Just return a nil account and nil error if no account is found
2. Return a custom error type like this:

```golang
type accountNotFoundErr struct {
    id uuid.UUID
}

func (err accountNotFoundErr) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("account not found for user: %v", err.id)
}

func IsAccountNotFoundErr(err error) bool {
    _, ok := err.(accountNotFoundErr)
    return ok
}

func GetAccount(ctx context.Context, id uuid.UUID) (*Account, error) {
    // if the account is not found
    return nil, accountNotFoundErr{id}
}
```

I like the first one because it's simple, but I don't often see Go code which returns a nil result if the error is non-nil. I think the expectation is that, if the error is nil, the result is valid. The second approach fixes that, but it's also a bit more complicated for callers.

What is an idiomatic approach for handling cases like this in Go?

Comment: You should decide if finding no account is an error. This may vary from function to function / use case to use case. E.g. if during login a user specifies a user name, looking up that account may easily not exist (the user may have mistyped the user name). But if you want to lookup a logged in account, if he/she has already logged in, the account must exist, finding no account in this case does mean an error. Whatever the case may be, it's always good to document how your function behaves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have read a lot of posts about custom errors in go. Most of them created their own struct that implements the error interface.

The issue I found with that approach was that I did not manage to easily check if an error was of a certain *type*. The same way, you may be able to check some std lib error like `if error == EOF`.

Therefore, my favourite way to do that is creating a simple var with `erros.New`.

```golang
var ErrNotFound = errors.New("Resource was not found")

func main() {
    err := raise()
    if err == ErrNotFound {
        fmt.Println("impossibru")
        return
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unexpected error")
        return
    }
}

func raise() error {
    return ErrNotFound
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/s0ZQfsdLqxB

As @Gavin pointed out in the comments, if you want to provide more context to the error by wrapping it with `fmt.Errorf`, you need to use `errors.Is` to check if the specific error was wrapped.

```golang
var ErrNotFound = errors.New("Resource was not found")

func main() {
    err := raise(42)
    if errors.Is(err, ErrNotFound) {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unexpected error")
        return
    }
}

func raise(id int) error {
    return fmt.Errorf("id %d does not exist, error: %w", id, ErrNotFound)
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/hSrkb1Xp4Hn

Comment: This will fail if the error is wrapped. Instead, you should use `if errors.Is(err, ErrNotFound)`. https://play.golang.com/p/536y_bh7_jy

Comment: Should we to that with every error? Or only ones that may be wrapped? Because most of the code I see is not using `errors.Is`. I.e. `if err := server.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {}`.

Comment: But your example is good. I never used that technique.  Makes sense to add some more context sometimes.

Comment: The `ListenAndServe()` example you've provided does not care what the error returned is, only that there is an error. If you are interested in a specific error, then yes, you should *almost* always use `errors.Is`.

Comment: @Gavin, OK thanks for the tip. I have added that to my answer.

Comment: @Gavin, you are right that inside the block at the `ListenAndServce` block, the error is generic. But in the if condition, it isn't. If the error was wrapped in that instance, the if check would not detect that it's `ErrServerClosed`. So I think the example is valid. It showcases, that when you know an error is not wrapped returned from a function, then there is no point of using `errors.Is`. In case of `ListenAndServce`, we know it will never come wrapped. Although, it may be still saver to do it, since you can never know when someone changes the function you are calling.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I like that there's just a single instance of the error, but I don't like that clients have to be aware of `errors.Is`, and I also don't like that clients have the ability to modify the global variable representing an account not found error. I ended up with a slightly modified approach here, but I'll accept this answer because it's what helped me get there: https://gist.github.com/MichaelSnowden/a5f980f18c17a0c00a3b5570a122518c